# iOS - Memory warning unloads the View Controller and makes the app unresponsive

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Body:
I am getting a Memory warning in my app, after which the UI stops responding. And, in the XCode logs I do see ViewController being Unloaded message.
I am afraid it is because I am not handling the transitions between the views properly and which is causing this memory issue.

Brief description of the ViewControllers**(VC)** I have and how I perform the transition:
I have 1 main/home VC which is the start of the main workflow of my app. 
And from all other VCs, I have links to come back to the Home VC.
So, instead of having Segues from all the VCs to the 1st one, I use the following way:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
HomeViewController *homeViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
[self presentViewController:homeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Intention was to just avoid having so many Segues from all the Views connecting to the Home View.

I feel this way of transition is causing the memory issue. Same View is getting added to the stack several times and causing the issue.
I am no expert of iOS, so any help/suggestion will be of great help to me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the way you have it you're creating an entirely new ViewController everytime you  intend to transition back to the HomeView. This is a very bad idea because everytime you make a transition you're putting a new view controller on the stack, rather than using the original ViewController (which you should be doing).

So as you keep making a transition, you're allocating new memory which eventually causes a memory warning then causes a stack overflow making your app crash.

HomeViewController should be presenting other view controllers using this method presentViewController:animated:completion: and dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: or something similar in order to perform transitions if you don't want to use segues.

Please read this apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case the workflow involves 3-4 view starting from HomeView. But even from 4th view, I should be able to get back to the Home. How do I use the above mentioned solution in this kind of case?

Comment: The link I provided, if you read it thoroughly, will explain how to manage multi view applications, how to present and dismiss them and how they are allocated and memory managed.